# Документация по Discord HTTPS API

Tags: api, discord, https

Я никак не могу найти документацию по Discord HTTPS API, это не модуль и не библиотека, это обращение к серверам Discord напрямую.

Пример: [https://canary.discord.com/api/v8/channels/{channel}/messages/?content=test?tts=False](https://canary.discord.com/api/v8/channels/%7Bchannel%7D/messages/?content=test?tts=False).

Этот пример отправит сообщение `test` в канал `channel`. Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#api-reference-base-url), но документацию я так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уже нашли документацию. Думаю, больше всего Вам будут интересны разделы `INTERACTIONS` и `RESOURCES`.

Например, вот документация по приведённому Вами методу: [Create Message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message).

> Post a message to a guild text or DM channel. Returns a [message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object) object. Fires a [Message Create](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#message-create) Gateway event. See [message formatting](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting) for more information on how to properly format messages.

Comment: спасибо большое